# Is Forest Druid weak?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, druid

I am hardcore rookie at D&D but I am already hooked up. After the last gaming day we all got level 2 and have to decide which path we choose for our characters. I am a hunter and my girlfriend is a druid. She wants do fight with spells and not as an animal so she decided to go for the Land/Forest path but this path looks very weak to me.

- Bonus Cantrip - Nice to have but not very essential.
- Natural Recovery - Nice to have too but recovering a few spells with a short rest instead of a long rest doesn't look like that big of a deal to me.
- Circle Spells Forest - Plant growth and tree stride, how often can she really use this?
- Land's Stride - In a fighting situation she normally doesn't have to walk around and in a non fighting situation she can walk at normal speed, but the rest of the group can't, so what use does this ability have?
- Nature's Ward - Nice to have but not a real game changer.
- Nature's Sanctuary - Just useful for you if you fight against beasts or plants and because you are not the frontliner of the group. It does not have that much impact for the group.

I am a total beginner and maybe I am seeing this all wrong but land looks very weak compared to moon. As a Land Druid you have a lot of nice stuff but not a single game changer. As a moon Druid, every ability looks very good to me and something like *Elemental Wild Shape* looks like an extremely powerful ability. I guess the game designers make every path equally strong so what did I miss?

Comment: Since this has been put on hold, if you'd like opinions on these questions, you can [ask chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)

Comment: I am concerned this is a bit too opinion-based - "is it weak" assumes both a clear compare (just vs moon druid) and a use (one on one combat?). Perhaps a question edit to where there can be a best answer to clear requirements and not just opinion/discussion.

Comment: i really want to answer this despite the fact that it's on hold. is that really a problem? because this seems a reasonable question to me, as long as my answer ISNT opinionated

Comment: Yes it is - work to get it improved and reopened instead.

Comment: @tobias michael alright, just write the question as "what are the primary differences in play style between moon and land druid, and are either RAW stronger"

Comment: You may consider asking your question on [forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).